# @Pointcut for all server request doesn't work with test context

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop, intersection

I try some variant with @pointcut to intercept all request to server, but they doesn't work with test context.

My examples

```
@Pointcut("execution (public * example.server.web.rest..*(..))")
@Pointcut("within(example.server.web.rest..*)")
@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *)")
```

I just want catch all request with test context. How to set the necessary context?

Updated

```
@Aspect
public class UsersAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution (public * example.server.web.rest..*(..))")
    public void allServerRequests() {
    }

    @Around(value = "allServerRequests()")
    public Object allServerRequest(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
       //some code
        return pjp.proceed();

    }
}
```

configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class UserAspectConfiguration {

    private final UserService userService;

    public UserAspectConfiguration(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Bean
    public UsersAspect userAspect(Environment env) {
        return new UsersAspect(userService, env);
    }
}
```

Example of test

```
       @Test
       @Transactional
       public void checkAllServerRequestAspect() throws Exception {
           UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
           userDTO.setSomething()
           userService.updateUser(userDTO);
           restUserMockMvc.perform(get("/api/any-rout")
               .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
               .andExpect(status().isForbidden());
       }
```

Now i can catch my test request only with like this pointcut

```
    @Pointcut("execution (public * example.server.service.UserService.*(..))")
```

But @pointcut for all server request not fired with test context, or something else(

Comment: Please provide a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least your build script, test code, controller code and Spring configuration.

Comment: jannis thank you for advice.

Comment: Then why don't you follow the advice?

Comment: kriegaex I followed the advice and added more details include an example of a test when updated question.